# How to change or add an ID to a SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, raphael

I have a SVG create with Raphael 2.0 which look like this :

```
<div class="stave">
<svg height="342" version="1.1" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;" viewBox="0 410 1300 80"
preserveAspectRatio="meet">
........
</svg>
</div>
```

i just want to set an ID to the svg tag! How can i do it? JQUERY or RAPHAEL 2.0?
i have see many answers but none works for me.

Thank you for helping

Comment: What code have you sued to generate the SVG. Is that the only SVG tag on the entire page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery you can use [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) and [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

Something like this: ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgvqE/))

```
<div class="frame">
    <div>div1</div>
    <div>div2</div>
    <div>div3</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('div').css({'font-weight':'bold'});
    $('.frame div:nth-child(2)').attr("id","newId");
    $('#newId').css({'color':'#f30'})
</script>
```

Of course, in your case, selector would be `$('svg')`

Comment: Love it! I prefered this One cause i want to use jquery for most things!

Comment: @trouble I love jQuery too, but that's a sad comment.

Comment: Because as a rule, we use vanilla JS if we can.

Answer (score 8):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].id = 'svg_id';
```

That should work if you have only one SVG tag on your page and if you've called it after having created the tag using Raphael.

If you haven't created the tag using Raphael, you can just use something like this:

```
<svg id='svg_id'></svg>
```

Along with the other attributes, of course.

Answer (score 3):

```
var paper=Raphael(0, 0, 342, 512)
paper.canvas.id='id_svg1'
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: as `paper.canvas` you access the right one SVG `<svg ..` element (not as DOM element)